# Parameter with that name [userName] did not exist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have this Hibernate/JPA code:

```
List<User> users = getEntityManager().createQuery("from com.xxx.xxx.persistence.model.User where name    = :userName")
    .setParameter("userName", name.toLowerCase())
    .getResultList();
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [userName] did not exist
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.findParameterRegistration(BaseQueryImpl.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32)
```

If I hard code the userName in the SQL,  remove the setParamter, it works.  What is happening?

Comment: Didn't you replace `:username` to `:userName` writing SO questing? I had the same problem, first parameter of `setParameter` is case sensitive...

Comment: I didn't mean to go SO questing.  The previous question had gotten off track so I thought I would start fresh. This is the original code, and the case matches. So I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I had the similar issue but surrounding the named parameter (like `where name = (:userName)`) resolved the issue

Answer (score 8):

For the people looking for other solutions, check if You did not put semicolon right after your parameter(for example if you copy native query).

Example:

```
Query query = getEm().createNativeQuery("Select * from a where a.id = :id;");
query.setParameter("id", 1);
```

This won't work, cause it will look for parameter "id" but your real parameter name is "id;".